# Angular & Eslint - no-floating-promises error with this.router.navigate(['/'])

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint, eslintrc

I've got the following eslint error:

> Promises must be handled appropriately or explicitly marked as ignored
> with the `void` operator.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises

with this code:

```
this.router.navigate(['/']);
```

the router is imported like this: `import { Router } from '@angular/router';` and assigned in the constructor of the class.

My eslint config:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
    // "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates",
    'prettier',
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    project: './tsconfig.eslint.json',
    sourceType: 'module',
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', '@angular-eslint', 'prettier'],
  rules: {
    "prettier/prettier": [
      "error",
      {
        "printWidth": 140,
        "singleQuote": true,
        "useTabs": false,
        "tabWidth": 2,
        "semi": true,
        "bracketSpacing": true,
        "endOfLine": "lf"
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Is my config wrong oder what's the problem? I feel like router.navigate shouldn't be an eslint error in an angular project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The rule [#no-floating-promises](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-floating-promises.md) says:

> This rule forbids usage of Promise-like values in statements without handling
> their errors appropriately

So here you are not handling `this.router.navigate` appropriately because it returns a `Promise`.

You can either:

1. Wait for it to return

   ```js
   await this.router.navigate(['/']);
   ```
2. Explicitly mark it as intentionally not awaited

   ```js
   void this.router.navigate(['/']);
   ```
3. Disable the rule for this specific line

   ```js
   // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises
   this.router.navigate(['/']);
   ```

Comment: I like the second option. Thanks.

Comment: For anyone else who persistently gets this lint error and has been trying to figure out how to deal with it, there is a 4th option: chaining `.then()` and `.catch()` code to the function call.

Answer (score 1):

I added `'@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises': 'warn'` rule to eslint config.

Comment: Yes, but then I still get a warning message. I want router.navigate to never have a warning at all. But somewhere else that error / warning might be useful, which is why I don't want to turn off that rule.

Comment: yes i understand and thats the reason i did not completly turn off that rule. however i am not sure how to turn it off conditionally